# how can I select elements I created and appended with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

essentially I created new divs through JavaScript.
append them to a div container.
and then try to select them all in JavaScript with the same class like this
const cards=document.querySelectorAll('.card');
but it says its null

how can I select them all after I created them in JavaScript?

Comment: could you share a minimum reproducible sample of your issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't shared a sample yet, I followed the logic based on the information you provided and I created a small example of 2 div's
appending them in another div. As you can see all the divs can be found in your container with `console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('class'))`.

```js
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.className = 'class'

var div2 = document.createElement("div");
div2.className = 'class';

var element = document.getElementById('id')
element.appendChild(div)
element.appendChild(div2)

console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('class'))
```

```html
<div id="id"></div>
```